# Using Visual basic 2017 to navigate to a esp8266 wifi switch (Sonoff)

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control

I am using the below code to navigate to a specific web address as follows :

```
WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://192.168.0.157/cm?cmnd=POWER%20Toggle"
```

The fact is that the the link returns a *.json* file and the `WebBrowser` controls displays the default save file dialog asking if i want to save the file or run it.

I want to ignore it the dialog and read from the *.json* file directly(i mean after downloading it).

I just want to get rid of the **Save dialog** of the webbrowser.I am a newbie so i don't know what to search or how to ask properly.

Comment: If the file is returned immediately and if the web browser _doesn't_ display a page, perhaps you could just remove the web browser and use [**`WebClient.DownloadString()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadstring(v=vs.110).aspx) or [**`WebClient.DownloadFile()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadfile(v=vs.110).aspx) instead?

Answer (score 1):

Though your post is not even close to be standard and hardly explains the issue, what i understand so far is that you have a few issues and i will answer them separately.

**Disabling the download dialog of the webbrowser and downloading the files automatically**

Firstly, you mentioned **it** returns a **.json** file. So , you can easily add a `SaveFileDialog`to your form or set a custom path(maybe in a variable) and check if the webbrowser is trying to download any *.json* files. Then you will `Cancel` the call(typically i mean that cancel the popup that says **Save** , **Run** ...) and make use of the `SaveFileDialog` or the local variable to save the file directly to disk. Here's a sample which uses a local string variable as the path and saves the *.json* file directly to disk :

```
 Imports System.ComponentModel
 ...

 Dim filepath As String '''class lever variable

 Private Sub myBroswer_Navigating(sender as Object, e As WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs) Handles myBroswer.Navigating


  If e.Url.Segments(e.Url.Segments.Length - 1).EndsWith(".json") Then
    e.Cancel = True
    filepath = "C:\test\" + e.Url.Segments(e.Url.Segments.Length - 1)
    Dim client As WebClient = New WebClient()
    AddHandler client.DownloadFileCompleted , AddressOf New AsyncCompletedEventHandler(DisplayJson);   
    client.DownloadFileAsync(e.Url, filepath)     
End If
End Sub
```

**Displaying the result AKA .json**

It is very easy to de-serialize/parse .json files.But first, download [this](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) , extract the ZIP and `Add Reference` to `Newtonsoft.Json.dll`. Now consider the bellow code snippet :

```
 Private Sub DisplayJson()
   Dim parseJson = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllLines(filepath))

   MsgBox(parseJson("element name here").ToString)
 End sub
```

Hope this helps